# Why is "windows logon user interface host" using my webcam?

Tags: windows-8.1, webcam, kaspersky

I just got a message from my internet security program (Kaspersky) saying:

> windows logon user interface host is using webcam

Why on earth is it doing this? Can I stop it?

I'm using Windows 8.1 on an 8"  Asus tablet if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t mention the manufacturer, but Dell has [Dell FastAccess 3.0 Facial Recognition Software](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN147279/EN) to bypass password login, and there are add-on applications such as KeyLemon that serve the same purpose.

If you do not use that feature, it might be best to *disable* the service, rather than to uninstall the software, in case you wish to sell the PC or you change your mind.

Comment: it says in the question it's an asus tablet

Comment: There is a thread on Asus facial recognition at http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/transformer-prime-general-discussions/23554-face-recognition-question.html. Sorry I missed your note at the end.